# Google Analytics: One page tracking multiple queries

Tags: php, javascript, html, input, google-analytics

I have a simple PHP/HTML website that contains 3 steps of user input requirements. A pseudo flow process would look like:

`(Page 1) Step 1: Enter x_input`

`(Page 2) Step 2: Enter y_input`

`(Page 3) Step 3: Enter z_input`

The progress of each step is to be tracked by Google Analytics. Currently, in order to properly track if each step is being completed by the user, each step is it's own individual page.

Ideally, I would like to condense this information down to 1 page for simplicity. Is there a way to still track each completed "step" and sort of treat it as it's own page for GA? The method of how it would be distinguished does not matter (PHP, javascript, whatever). Any thoughts/comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be achieved by using goals within google analitycs

On the left hand side of the analytics for your site there is a section called "conversions" you can open this and then access "goals".

I haven't done this myself but you can add goal URL's so maybe you can condense this flow to one page and pass parameters via the query string to identify which step of the process you are on, and add these urls to the goals within google analytics.

Comment: Yes i just discovered Goals before you posted. This is exactly what I need! I think there's a bunch of ways I can accomplish what I want here. Thanks!

Comment: You can also set up the individual steps as funnels to your Goal -- take a look at [About Goals](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012040) & [Flow analysis of Goals and Funnels](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1686005)